# Всегда ли надо ли возвращать IActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Надо ли возвращать IActionResult во всех случаях когда результата работы функции нет?

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ReturnIActionResult() {
    await DoSomthing();
    return Ok();
}

public async Task ReturnNothing() {
    await DoSomthing();
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду TaskResultExecutor ([здесь](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ActionMethodExecutor.cs)), во втором случае по-видимому вернётcя EmptyResult.

Comment: Http работает по принципу запрос-ответ, потому что то клиету за надо вернуть, хотя бы просто код ответа.

Comment: @tym32167 но во втором случае `ReturnNothing` разве не 200 будет возвращено?

Comment: EmptyResult - это статус 200 с пустым body.

Comment: Ваш код я не могу проверить, потому хз что он вернет :) Не занимаюсь веб разработокой уже довольно давно.

Comment: @tym32167 я протестировал и оба варианта вернули 200 OK

Comment: отлично, значит все работает